# esrally.exceptions.SystemSetupError: ('JAVA_HOME points to JDK 8 but it should point to JDK 10.', None) when running a race on esrally

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

The Dockerfile of my docker 17.03.1-ce is as follows

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Specifying versions is better??
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
                python3 \
                python3-pip \
                git \
                gradle \
                vim \
                wget \
                openjdk-8-jdk

RUN pip3 install esrally

RUN apt-get clean && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd  -ms /bin/bash esrally

USER esrally

WORKDIR /home/esrally

RUN echo "export http_proxy=${http_proxy}" > /home/esrally/.bashrc
RUN git config --global http.proxy ${http_proxy}

RUN esrally configure --assume-defaults
RUN esrally list tracks
RUN mkdir ~/.rally/benchmarks/tracks/default/tsgraph

COPY track-tsgraph/*.json /home/esrally/.rally/benchmarks/tracks/default/tsgraph/

RUN mkdir /home/esrally/esrally-docker
COPY . /home/esrally/esrally-docker/

RUN mkdir -p /home/esrally/downloads; \
    cd /home/esrally/downloads; \
    wget wget -e use_proxy=yes -e HTTP_PROXY=${http_proxy} http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz; \
    cd /home/esrally; tar -zxvf /home/esrally/downloads/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz;
```

It currently has jdk 8 in it. But when I create a container and try to run a trial race "esrally" on it, it asks me for jdk10 installation.

```
    ____        ____
   / __ \____ _/ / /_  __
  / /_/ / __ `/ / / / / /
 / _, _/ /_/ / / / /_/ /
/_/ |_|\__,_/_/_/\__, /
                /____/

[WARNING] No Internet connection detected. Automatic download of track data sets etc. is disabled.
[INFO] Preparing for race ...
[ERROR] Cannot race. ('JAVA_HOME points to JDK 8 but it should point to JDK 10.', None)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/esrally/mechanic/mechanic.py", line 540, in receiveMsg_StartNodes
    msg.distribution, msg.external, msg.docker)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/esrally/mechanic/mechanic.py", line 631, in create
    s = supplier.create(cfg, sources, distribution, build, challenge_root_path, car, plugins)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/esrally/mechanic/supplier.py", line 27, in create
    java_home = _java_home(car)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/esrally/mechanic/supplier.py", line 81, in _java_home
    _, path = jvm.resolve_path(int(build_jdk))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/esrally/utils/jvm.py", line 94, in resolve_path
    return majors, _resolve_single_path(majors, sysprop_reader=sysprop_reader)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/esrally/utils/jvm.py", line 134, in _resolve_single_path
    java_home = do_resolve(generic_env_var, major)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/esrally/utils/jvm.py", line 121, in do_resolve
    raise exceptions.SystemSetupError("{} points to JDK {} but it should point to JDK {}.".format(env_var, actual_major, major))
esrally.exceptions.SystemSetupError: ('JAVA_HOME points to JDK 8 but it should point to JDK 10.', None)


Getting further help:
*********************
* Check the log files in /Users/ndoke/.rally/logs for errors.
* Read the documentation at https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/
* Ask a question on the forum at https://discuss.elastic.co/c/elasticsearch/rally
* Raise an issue at https://github.com/elastic/rally/issues and include the log files in /Users/ndoke/.rally/logs.

-------------------------------
[INFO] FAILURE (took 2 seconds)
-------------------------------
```

Can some let me know why this is happening. If there is no work around to get this running with jdk 8. Can someone let me know a step by step procedure of installing jdk 10 in my docker.

Answer (score -2):

.rally/benchmarks/teams/default/cars/v1/vanilla

edit config.ini file for the correct java version

Comment: This needs a lot more explanation.